# Month distance between two full dates-only

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Well, I need get two values that represents the distance between two full dates-only (no hour/time)... On MySQL we have `PERIOD_DIFF` that get the diff between two dates (only month and year), but I need to include the day too.

I have two dates like:

- `2011-12-05` and `2012-01-10`. After `2012-01-05` I have 1 full month, more 5 days.
- `2012-01-01` and `2012-03-01`. I have 2 months and 0 day.
- `2012-02-29` and `2012-03-28`¹. I have 0 month and 28 days. **More**: for 1 month, I need `2012-03-29`.
- `2013-01-29` and `2013-02-28`². I have 0 month and 30 days. **More**: for 1 month, I need `2013-03-01`, because `2013-02-29` not exists.
- `2013-03-31` and `2013-04-30`. **Fix**: *really* I have 0 month and 30 days. **More**: for 1 month, I need `2013-05-01`, because `2013-04-31` not exists.

¹ `2012` is a leap year / bissexto;
² `2013` is not;

I don't know what I need do exactly to solve that.

Comment: After you get amount of `months` with `PERIOD_DIFF` you can add it to the smaller date and after that subtract to get amount of days :-)

Comment: Am I missing something or `2013-03-31` and `2013-04-30` i exactly 1 month period because period between last day of one month and last day of next month is a month?

Comment: I like @zerkms's solution better than any of the answers given :-)

Comment: @piotrekkr: for some unknown reason OP wants `2013-03-31 - 2013-04-30` = `2013-03-30 - 2013-04-30` = `1 Month` :-S

Comment: @BRPocock his method won't work for `2013-01-29 and 2013-02-28` because PERIOD_DIFF will say it's 1 month difference, then you add 1 month to `2013-01-29` and you have `2013-02-28`. After substraction number of days will be 0. `1 month 0 days` is incorrect. Same incorrect values will be for `2012-02-29 and 2012-03-28` (1 month -1 day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set some variable for **total difference in months** to 0.

Use `DATEDIFF` to get the **total difference in days** between your start and end date.

For each month **between** your start and end month (*if there are any months in between*), use `LAST_DAY` and `DATEDIFF` to calculate the **number of days for that month**.

Subtract the **number of days for that month** from the **total difference in days**, and **add 1** to the **total difference in months**.

Comment: I accepted it because it help to discovery my answer. I'll edit it on future. ;) Thanks for all, be really useful.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this:

```
SET @start = '2013-03-31';
SET @end = '2013-04-30';
-- date @start is last day of month ?
SET @start_last = @start = LAST_DAY(@start);
-- date @end is last day of month ?
SET @end_last = @end = LAST_DAY(@end);

-- checking if difference is more than month
SET @month_or_more =IF(@start_last AND @end_last OR DAY(@start) = DAY(@end), DATE_ADD(@start, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) <= @end, DATE_ADD(@start, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) < @end);
-- diff in months
SET @m_num = IF(@month_or_more, PERIOD_DIFF( DATE_FORMAT(@end, '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(@start, '%Y%m')), 0);
-- diff in days
SET @d_num = DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(@start, INTERVAL @m_num MONTH), @end);

SELECT ABS(@m_num) as month,  ABS(@d_num) as days;
```

// **EDIT** fixed version